# Size of a gstreamer buffer to allocate

Tags: c++, udp, streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am working with a gstreamer sample found in [gstreamer.freedesktop.org](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-data-spoof.html) and work with this piece of code:

```
size = 385 * 288 * 2;
buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate (NULL, size, NULL);
...
/* setup */
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "caps",
    gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-raw",
                 "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB16",
                 "width", G_TYPE_INT, 384,
                 "height", G_TYPE_INT, 288,
                 "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 0, 1,
                 NULL), NULL);
```

I wonder why caps initialized with width 384 but buffer is allocated with value of 385.
When I try to use this code in my own purposes, it still require buffer to be allocated with a width+1 value, so my code looks like:

```
guint size = (nWidth + 1) * nHeight * sizeof(BUFFER_ELEMENT);    // IDK Y, but nWidth needs to be +1 as it made in a sample
buffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, size, NULL);
```

If "+ 1" removed, I'll get a black screen in autovideosink

So the question is: what's the magic of this trick and how gst_buffer_new_allocate() function work so it require it? Maybe it still can stop working again or crash or somethin' else in other conditions?
Thanks

Comment: It seems a simple case of 0 based indices, 0 - 385 whilst caps work on the normal indexing for example a width of 320 is 320 and not 320 + 1.

Comment: My source picture is 384*288 = 110592 pixels, obviously buffer should require 110592*3 = 331776 bytes but it doesn't work with buffer allocated with this size. It works with buffer of 385*288*3 = 332640 bytes that is 864 bytes longer than expected. The question was, what for is these 864 bytes and isn't it a kind of fixed buffer needed or whatever? I believe adding 1 to width is wrong  practice and can cause problems.